# Tkinter mouse event initially triggered

Tags: python, macos, events, tkinter

I'm currently learning Tkinter and I cannot find a solution for my problem here nor outside Stackoverflow. In a nutshell, all events that I bind to my widgets are triggered initialy and don't respond to my actions.

In this example, the red rectangle appears on the canvas when I run the code, and

```
color=random.choice(['red', 'blue'])
```

revealed that the event binding doesn't work after that:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.can = tk.Canvas(master, width=200, height=200)
        self.can.bind('<Button-2>', self.draw())
        self.can.grid()
    def draw(self):
        self.can.create_rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100, fill='red')

app = application()
app.mainloop()
```

I use a Mac platform, but I haven't got a clue about its role in the problem. Could anyone please point me at the mistake i did here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things here:

1. You should not be calling `self.draw` when you bind it to `<Button-2>`.
2. When you click `<Button-2>`, an event object will be sent to `self.draw`.  Thus, you need to make your function accept this argument, even if it does not use it.

In all, your script should look like this (the lines I changed are in comment boxes):

```
import Tkinter as tk

class application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.can = tk.Canvas(master, width=200, height=200)
        #######################################
        self.can.bind('<Button-2>', self.draw)
        #######################################
        self.can.grid()
    #######################
    def draw(self, event):
    #######################
        self.can.create_rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100, fill='red')

app = application()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked fine for me. But I have another question then - how do I do buttons? When I make a button, I use command=funcname, and if I don't add the "event" argument here, I get an error. Removing event from the function args list works, but that's not the right stuff to do, I suppose?

Comment: @AlexAgapov - No, that is correct.  `Tkinter.Button` does _not_ send an event object to the function.  Only bindings do that, like in your example.  So, if you have a function that will be used with a `Tkinter.Button`, just leave out the event argument.  You only need the event argument with bindings.

Comment: @AlexAgapov - Also, if you have a function that will be used with both a binding and a `Tkinter.Button`, you should leave out the event argument and instead use a lambda function with the binding.  For example:  `self.can.bind('<Button-2>', lambda event: self.draw())`

Comment: So if I need to bind my function both to mouse and to a button (though I hardly see any chance for that), I'll have to make two different functions?

edit: didn't see your last answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Even though this question is not the newest one - if you want to use it with a Button and a binding, you could set the event parameter to optional using `def function_name(self, event=None):` so your event object is by default initialized with `None`. Thus you can (if necessary) also check if your function was called by Button-command or Binding.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your code.

1.`self.can.bind('<Button-2>', self.draw())`

You should not make a method call. You should assign a method which should be called, when Button-2 is clicked

`self.can.bind('<Button-2>', self.draw)`

2.`def draw(self)`

Most of the times, an event object will be passed. You should change that line to

`def draw(self, event)`.

In the future, once you are familiar with the basics, you will be using the event object and also learn about why it is getting passed.